# Running Symfony on OpenLiteSpeed (htaccess issue)

Tags: symfony, litespeed

I'm running OpenLiteSpeed as my web server and it doesn't seem to support .htaccess which is causing issues with Symfony not loading url's properly.

Does anyone know how to configure Symfony to run on OpenLiteSpeed? (Seems mainly to be rewrite related.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenLiteSpeed does not read .htaccess by default. 
The best way to deal with directory level rewrite configurations is to create a "static" context under that vhost, then copy rewrite rules from .htaccess to the context configuration.

Comment: Works perfectly, copied everything from the mod_rewrite section into the rules section / context and enabled rewrite rules on vhost. Thanks